# Link to create action with phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to fire a create action with a link to using link_helpers in Phoenix. But there doesn't seem to be an obvious answer to this so that leads me to think that maybe this is a bad practice?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
<%= link "Create Prediction Points", to: prediction_score_path(@conn, :create) %>
```

Error:

```
function StatcastersWeb.PredictionScoreController.index/2 is undefined or private
```

Is there a way to do this? If so, should I?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? Looks like the name of the function in your controller is wrong or doesn't take 2 arguments.

Comment: Also, what does your route definition look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any action that may change something on the server should be behind an HTTP POST and not an HTTP GET. So even if you can set up a link to the `create` action in the controller, which we definitely can and we will get to that in a second, doing so is not recommended because `create` actions typically *create* something in the server and if you put that behind a link it could be accessed accidentally by a browser plugin, a crawler or something of sorts.

That said, if you run `mix phx.routes` in your application, you will see the following routes:

```
GET  /prediction_scores/ index
POST /prediction_scores/ create
```

i.e. the URL is the same but what changes between requests is the HTTP verb (GET vs POST). That's why it is trying to invoke `index/2`, instead of `create/2`. You could fix it in two ways:

1. If the action you have on the server is effectively creating new resources, than you want to keep it as POST create, so you have to pass the `method: :post` option at the end of your `link` function call.
2. If the action you have on the server is just going to render something, then you should rather use the `index` action or another create that you can create in your router+controller.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Super helpful